# How to append or insert text in google spreadsheet column when new record generates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCN01.png)

I have a google spreadsheet where I am getting entries automatically from website. I want to insert a special text like "s36" in next cell automatically whenever new entries appear in sheet.
Once 40 entries done wit s36 then next 40 should be of s37 and so on.

Please guide me how to do this with google spreadsheet script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check the attached image.

Comment: Use array formula and compare the row with upper row

Comment: But, are the rows between s36 and s37 blank cells?

Comment: I do also have trouble understanding what is exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do you always want a 40 gap? Do you need to start at s36? How are you "automatically" retrieving the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this formula (I begin from A240 and span 4, change as needed):

a. blank between (Family Name1):

```
=filter
   (   
     if( mod(row(A240:A)-row(A240),4)=0,
         "S" & 36 + ((row(A240:A)-row(A240))/4)
         ,""
       )  
     ,A240:A<>""
   )
```

b. No Blank Between  (Family Name2):

```
=filter
   (   
     "S" & 36 + int(((row(A240:A)-row(A240))/4))    
     ,A240:A<>""
   )
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for help. it works exactly like i want.